# How does MySQL Workbench decide what number to put in parentheses after a datatype?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I create columns in MySQL Workbench and it often puts different numbers in parentheses after datatype, e.g. I input this:

```
Column Name          Datatype:
id                   INT
account_parameters   INT
accounts             TINYINT
account_properties   TINYINT
```

and after executing the query I get

```
Column Name          Datatype:
id                   INT(10)
account_parameters   INT(11)
accounts             TINYINT(1)
account_properties   TINYINT(2)
```

Why does it do it? Is there a reason why one should be INT(11), while others are INT(10)?

Comment: And the number means _nothing_ (unless you use `ZEROFILL`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the difference is likely due to the `int` and `tinyint` being `signed` (default) or `unsigned` in their definitions. Note that the numbers in the parentheses are largely irrelevant for most applications (they define a display width).